# Nodejs: question of type input with npm inquirer not working

Tags: node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

I am using `npm inquirer` for the first time.

I am using a code similar to this:

```js
const inquirer = require("inquirer");

const questions = [
  {
    type: "checkbox",
    name: "collections.telemetria",
    message: "Select collections of database telemetria",
    choices: [
      "chimera-11/14/2019,-4:22:38-PM",
      "chimera-11/14/2019,-4:28:26-PM"
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "checkbox",
    name: "collections.testa",
    message: "Select collections of database testa",
    choices: ["testa_c"]
  }
];

async function main() {
  const collections = (await inquirer.prompt(questions)).collections;
  console.log("collections:", collections);
  const outPath = await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "outPath",
      default: "./",
      message: "Insert the output path"
    }
  ]).outPath;
  console.log(outPath);
}
main();
```

The problem is that when it comes to the question of type input to be answered, the word undefined appears and I cannot put any input.

[image]

Here is a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-kowalevski-dgg5u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of [Shivam Sood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7482427/shivam-sood), I found that there was only a mistake in the code. I forgot to put the `await inquirer.prompt([...])` inside the parenthesis before calling the property `outPath` of the expected result.

So the right code should be:

```js
const outPath = (await inquirer.prompt([
    {
      type: "input",
      name: "outPath",
      default: "./",
      message: "Insert the output path"
    }
  ])).outPath;
  console.log(outPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the `console.log(outPath)` as that returns `undefined` making the `terminal` unusable. Remove  `console.log(outPath)` and it should work.

I'm not really sure what `.outPath` at the end does but you can remove that to make `console.log(outPath)` to work.

So either remove `console.log()` or `.outPath` depending on requirement.

As you probalbly already know that `inquirer.prompt` returns a promise if you want the result you can do something like this

```
      const outPath = inquirer.prompt([
        {
          type: "input",
          name: "outPath",
          default: "./",
          message: "Insert the output path"
        }
      ]).then(response=>{
           console.log(response)
})
```

Here you can see it runs for me If I remove `.outPath`

[image: Code Running]

Comment: I did not understand why you used both await and then in the same row

Comment: Ohh my bad, I forgot to mention I removed async/await and used promise instead